# Multi-select Dropbox

Tags: selection

how should I handle this multi-select for luggage selection. if I remove first bag the next step with throw an error. I was thinking should I only allow the user to delete the last item added or if the user deletes item piece one the 2nd replaces the 1st etc.

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! I don't understand your problem: There are 2 places for each item to remove it (top bar, input field), and there is a remove-all-luggage "x" button (input field). What is the problem with pushing any of them? Why does the next step (what is the next step?) throw an error? Which error? Allowing the user to only delete the last (or first) item is a bad idea, because that might not be what they want. For the passenger, there are three luggage items, and they don't have any particular order - don't impose an order on the passenger which is only needed for the system!

Answer (score 1):

For this particular situation, consider simply adding/ removing bags. Based on the count, the code can code/ recompute the total and show it to the user.

```
Number of bags: [   0   ]  [+]
Total: QAR 0
```

```
Number of bags: [   2   ]  [+] [-]
Total: QAR 1460
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong way of applying filters because they are not independent. In fact, I think they are not filters but categories dependent on the preceding one.

The alternative is to include buttons to add and remove subsequent categories:

[image]